# Sampling on Axis-Aligned Spherical Quad

Tags: probability, geometry, random-variables, spherical-coordinates, sampling

Given spherical coordinates on a unit sphere, imagine a spherical quad defined by two ranges $[\phi_0,\phi_1]$ and $[\theta_0,\theta_1]$.  If you have a globe, for example, the grid formed by the latitude and longitude lines is composed of the kind of quads I'm talking about.

I need to generate a random vector on the surface of this quad.  I think the quads decrease in area sinusoidally toward the poles, so I think maybe I could figure something out, but I was wondering if such an algorithm already exists, before I go trying to reinvent any wheels.

Comment: Assuming $\phi$ is latitude, pick $z$ uniformly between $z_0=\sin\phi_0$ and $z_1=\sin\phi_1$, and let $\phi=\sin^{-1}z$. The longitude $\theta$ you can pick uniformly between $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rahul's comment exploits a peculiar feature of two-dimensional sphere: the spherical area bounded between two parallel planes is proportional to the distance between them. ([See   here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalSegment.html)). This is why we can sample points uniformly on unit 2-sphere by choosing cylindrical coordinates: $z$ uniformly from $[-1,1]$ and longitude $\theta$ uniformly from $[0,2\pi]$. (The latitude is then calculated from $z$.)

Restriction to the   rectangular   region is accounted for by restricting $\theta$ and $z$ accordingly. For a  more complex shape one could use the usual process of generate - check - reject if outside.

Comment: Accepted because I tried it, and it works.  +1 for also explaining _why_.