# Spherical Sampling of Projected Disk

Tags: probability, random, sampling

Given a 2D solid disk centered at some 3D point $\vec{x}$ with radius $r$ and normal $\vec{N}$, I need to compute a random unit vector from the origin that hits the disk.  The vector needs to be uniformly random with respect to solid angle, and I also need the associated PDF.

I tried to get the area of the disk projected onto a unit sphere at the origin (the reciprocal of which is the PDF), but the integral is tricky, and in any case I still don't know how to do the sampling.

I am currently sampling the projection of the disk's bounding sphere, which is much easier.  However, this approach is inefficient.

How can this sampling be done, and what is the PDF?

Comment: Are you speaking of a 2-dimensional disk in 3-dimensional space?

Comment: Yes.  Edited a bit.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the disk is used only to define a cone in $\mathbb R^3$ (formed by half-lines from the origin that cross the disk). This cone will be a quadric surface, specifically an elliptic cone. That is, after rotation it is of the form $z\ge \sqrt{x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2}$. Then it's a problem of picking a unit vector from within this cone.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. Yes, that's sounds about it.  The key point is it's an _elliptic_-cross-section cone.  Rotating sounds like a nice idea, although I still don't know how you'd randomly sample the spherical ellipse uniformly.

Comment: After rotation, I would sample from spherical cap containing the ellipse, [as described here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/853983/147263) and reject points that fail the inequality for elliptic cone. If the cone is not extremely narrow, it's probably easier to  just sample points from the sphere and reject those outside the cone.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, "I am currently sampling the projection of the disk's bounding sphere" using a similar method.  I believe this is equivalent to your suggestion.  As above, the problem is that I would prefer not to do rejection sampling; in general the disk's projection can be quite elongated.

Comment: Di you find any solution for this question?

Comment: And what rotation we are talking about here?